# Restoring a database from a Batch File causes argument error

Tags: sql-server, batch-file

I'm trying to back up and restore a database directly from a bat-file.

```
set SqlServer=.
set DatabaseName=mydbname
set Username=test
set Password=test
set LocalFolder=C:\backups

chcp 65001
SQLCMD -S %SqlServer% -U %Username% -P %Password% -Q "BACKUP DATABASE [%DatabaseName%] 
TO DISK='%LocalFolder%\test.bak' WITH FORMAT"
```

And now, for restoring the database back, I use the same outline, but I keep getting an error.

```
set SqlServer=.
set DatabaseName=mydbname
set Username=test
set Password=test
set LocalFolder=C:\backups

chcp 65001
SQLCMD -S %SqlServer% -U %Username% -P %Password% –Q "RESTORE DATABASE [%DatabaseName%] 
FROM DISK='%LocalFolder%\test.bak'"
```

Error

> Sqlcmd: '–Q "RESTORE DATABASE [mydbname] FROM DISK='C:\backups\test.bak'': Unexpected argument. Enter '-?' for help.

Does anyone see a mistake in how I'm doing it?

Comment: It looks right, but I would still recommend using DbaTools in Powershell instead. You can just do `Restore-DbaDatabase -DatabaseName "mydbname" -Path "C:\backups\test.bak"`

Comment: Is there, out of interest, a good reason why you want to do this in an old MS-DOS style environment and not Powershell?

Comment: no, no reason actually...I have no experience with doing this in Powershell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have no experience with doing this in Powershell.

This is a good time to learn. CMD is much less powerful and harder to use than Powershell.

Anyway, you've got the wrong dash character in the second command.  Here's a hex dump from [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/Download), which also has a Powershell extension.

[image]